# Load value from SQL table in HTML textarea

Tags: php, html, sql

I want to load the data of a table in my SQL database in a HTML textarea (PHP page):

```
   <form action="" method="post">
   <textarea id="styled" name="content"></textarea>
   <br/><input type="submit" name="Update">
   </form>
```

So, I would like to load the text in my table into this textarea when the page loads. The query is simple: 
       "SELECT * FROM about WHERE id=20"

..but I have no idea how to load the result in a textarea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you did `mysqli_connect` etc.

```
<?php
$res = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM about WHERE id=20");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
$value = $row["the_column"];
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<textarea id="styled" name="content"><?php echo htmlentities($value);?></textarea>
<br/><input type="submit" name="Update">
</form>
```

If you're not using `mysqli` substitute those functions.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, this is what I was trying to do. Just one question, instead of mysql I am using mysqli. I read about both but what is the real difference?

Comment: In simple words: `mysqli` replaces `mysql`. `myslqi` is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

From [PDO tag wiki:](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)

```
<?php
// connect. have to be moved into separate file to be included
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8";
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);
$pdo = new PDO($dsn,'root','', $opt);

//getting data
$id  = 20;
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT text FROM about WHERE id=?");
$stm->execute(array($id));
$text = $stm->fetchColumn();

//echoing out
?>
<form method="post">
    <textarea id="styled" name="content"><?=htmlspecialchars($text)?></textarea>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="Update">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

just put your php retrieval code between textarea